# Cluster Automatically Removed from Databricks after lack of usage

Tags: cluster-computing, databricks, aws-databricks

Does anyone know how to retrieve a cluster that was auto removed from Databricks after not using it for some time? I added a bunch of libraries and global init scripts to it and it automatically got deleted after not using it for a month. I want to see what I did last time to either retrieve it or replicate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes . 30 days after a cluster is terminated, it is permanently deleted. To keep an all-purpose cluster configuration even after a cluster has been terminated for more than 30 days, an administrator can pin the cluster. Up to 70 clusters can be pinned.You can refer : [link](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/clusters-manage.html#pin-a-cluster)